# Counting with a bit mask

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to enumerate values that conform to a certain bit mask.

For instance, I want to enumerate all the bytes that contain the pattern `0xb5`.

A simple C program to achieve this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* prints out b5, b7, bd, bf, f5, f7, fd, ff */
int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {    
    const uint8_t mask = 0xb5;
    uint8_t i = 0;

    while(true) {
        if((i & mask) == mask) printf("%x\n", i);
        if(i == UINT8_MAX) break;
        i++; /* Replace by something smarter. */
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

However, regardless of the mask, this loop will iterate `UINT8_MAX` times. Is there a neat bit trick I can use to automatically increment `i` to the next value that satisfies the mask?

Comment: Well, you *could* identify how many zero bits there are in the mask, and then count over those (distributing bits to positions as required).  That certainly won't be faster than the naive solution, though.

Comment: You should at least use `i = mask` instead of `i = 0`

Comment: FYI, you have an infinite loop!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thanks! so much for trying to fix my off-by-one error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count only through the "wildcard bits", like this:

```
x = (x + 1) | pattern;
```

Assuming you start with `pattern` (the wildcard bits all zero).

The idea here is that the "pattern bits" are 1, so when you add one, the carry (if there is one) travels through them to the next section of "wildcard bits". Of course when a carry has traveled through, that leaves "pattern bits" at 0, so they're put back in.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Much simpler that I was fearing, too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `i++` you could use `i = ((i << 1) | 1);`

Comment: The first time he'll match will be at 0xb5.  With your formula, the next i would be 0x16B and would miss 0xf5 which matches the mask as well.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question? It seems to me that `i` would take on values 1,3,7,15,31,63,127,255 thereby simply turning on one more bit for each iteration.

Comment: @Logicrat it should be b5, b7, bd, bf, f5, f7, fd, ff

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on theme well stated by @harold

```
while (1) {
  printf("%x\n", i);  // no need for mask test
  if (i == UINT8_MAX)
    break;
  do {
    i++;
   } while ((i & mask) != mask);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that actually answers this question though

Comment: Updated post to replace `i++` with "something smarter".